# "La que" and "que"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, gramática

In the book *The Martian* by Andy Weir, the main character states:

> It was a ridiculous sequence of events that led to me almost dying, and an even more ridiculous sequence that led to me surviving.

In the Spanish translation, *El marciano*, he states:

> Fue una ridícula secuencia de hechos **la que** me llevó al borde de la muerte, y una secuencia aún más ridícula **la que** propició que sobreviviera.

Why is it "la que" instead of "que"? I'm not sure I see what the difference is.

(Also, I'm not sure why that's "sobreviviera" and not "sobrevivía". I understand that "sobreviviera" is subjunctive, but why are we using the subjunctive there?)

Comment: I also submitted this question here: http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/279472/la-que-and-que

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question because by adding 'la' the whole sentence structure changes. See how this sentence is parsed when 'la' is absent:

> (i) Fue una ridícula secuencia de hechos **que** me llevó al borde de la muerte.

- Subject: omitted 'it' (ello).
- Verb: fue
- DO: una ridícula secuencia de hechos que me llevó al borde de la muerte

The DO is a Noun Phrase (*sintagma nominal* in Spanish), where "secuencia" is the *núcleo*, and "que me llevó al borde de la muerte" is a complement of that *núcleo* (what we call in Spanish a *complemento de nombre*).

Now see how it's parsed when 'la' is present:

> (ii) Fue una ridícula secuencia de hechos **la que** me llevó al borde de la muerte.

- Subject: la que me llevó al borde de la muerte.
- Verb: fue
- DO: una ridícula secuencia de hechos

Here, the subject is a NP, whose original *núcleo* ("secuencia") has been elided to avoid repetition. The complete NP would be "la [secuencia] que me llevó al borde de la muerte".

So by adding the 'la' a different part of the sentence becomes the subject. In sentence (i), the subject is omitted. That would only make sense if there was a sequence of events already mentioned before, so the reader would be able to know *what* sequence the writer is talking about. Since in the book that sentence is at the beginning of a paragraph, the reader would be really puzzled as to *what* sequence the writer is talking about –that misterious sequence that would be the omitted subject.

In sentence (ii), on the other hand, the subject is "la [secuencia] que me llevó al borde de la muerte". Here you have a noun ("secuencia"), with a determiner ("la") and a *complemento* to that noun ("que me llevó al borde de la muerte"). Now *that* should be enough to identify *what* sequence the writer is talking about. With this last sentence, the reader has no concerns, he/she isn't puzzled and wondering *what the heck* the writer is talking about (which is a good thing when reading a book).

But this gets even more complex when the second part ("y una secuencia aún más ridícula la que propició que sobreviviera") is added. This one is harder to parse since it's not even a sentence, for it lacks a verb. The complete sentence would be:

> (iii) Y [fue] una secuencia aún más ridícula **que** propició que sobreviviera.
>
> Or...
>
> (iv) Y [fue] una secuencia aún más ridícula **la que** propició que sobreviviera.

In sentence (iii), the omitted subject (see parsing of sentence i) is the same as the one in the first part. But by saying "una ridícula secuencia" and "una secuencia aún más ridícula" you are saying they are *different* sequences. That is, how could something be "ridiculous" and "even more ridiculous" *at the same time*? By being more ridiculous than *itself*? As you can see, that interpretation doesn't hold water.

Now, by looking at sentence (iv), the subject is now "la [secuencia] que propició que sobreviviera" (see parsing of sentence ii). This subject is evidently different from the subject in the first part ("la secuencia que me llevó al borde de la muerte" vs "la secuencia que propició que sobreviviera"), so that makes it perfectly sensical that one is only "ridiculous" while the second is "even more ridiculous". I hope you can see now why 'la' is not only *less puzzling*, but strictly necessary there for the whole sentence to make sense.

This may seem a little bit too complex a parsing for readers to do it "on the go", but this is what any Spanish speaker does even without noticing they are doing it (and even those who can't parse). They may not be able to tell you what's not working there, but they will surely tell there's something wrong to it.

---

Concerning the subjunctive thing, that is harder to tell. All I can say is that "sobrevivía" is definitely not right. Imperfect Preterite (sobrevivía) is generally used for actions that last in time. You can't *be surviving*, you either *survive* or not. In any case, the question should be: why not "sobreviví" instead of "sobreviviera"? But *sobreviví* doesn't work either, you must use a subjunctive. The reason for using a subjunctive is that the author says that the "ridiculous sequence" is what would allow the protagonist to survive. It looks ahead to the future while the action is in the past (from [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/279472/la-que-and-que)).

Comment: Thanks! I also submitted the question [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/279472/la-que-and-que). At the time of writing there are three responses, and two claim that "que" is OK.

Comment: They're blaming the phrase "de hechos," actually, which you haven't really mentioned. Are they wrong?

Comment: Not to be pretentious but yes, they are. If "de hechos" really were a plausible alternative to be linked to "que" (and that's the reason why they say "la que" is a better option), then you would have a verb disagreement ("hechos" being plural and "llevó"/"propició" being singular). That should be enough to tell you there's no way "que" could possibly be linked to "hechos", making the "la" unnecessary (if that were the reason why it is necessary, I mean; I'm possitive it's strictly necessary). Actually, gringojrf is the only one who said something sensible so far.

Comment: If a masculine noun were used instead of secuencia, would I use "el que" or "lo que"?

Comment: Btw, I like JulianChivi's answer about the subjunctive thing. I"m adding it to my answer.

Comment: Both would be fine, although "el que" would sound more natural. Actually, you can also use "lo que" with "secuencia" (bare in mind "lo" is gender-neutral), but, once again, "la que" sounds more natural.

Comment: I did not know that "lo" is gender-neutral.

Comment: Well, not always. It is masculine when it is a pronoun (e.g., "yo lo vi [el accidente]" but "yo la vi [la partida]", but it is neutral when it's an article ("lo bueno", "lo divertido", etc.). It is also true that the adjective following "lo" is masculine, but that's an arbitrary thing given adjectives don't have a "neutral form", so, as usual, the gender chosen is the masculine by default, but that doesn't mean the article "lo" is masculine. For further clarification, see http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Lo%20art%C3%ADculo%20neutro.htm

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I highly recommend reading _The Martian_ if you haven't already; it's a great book. They also made it into a movie (_Misión Rescate_ outside of Spain, _Marte_ in Spain), by the way.

Comment: I've already downloaded it!

Comment: Although he says " 'Cause I'll surely die here" in the very first page, which made me realise I already know he won't, but  *Oh well!...*

Comment: Well, the only reason you think he won't die is because he's the main character. (Clearly he lived long enough to write that log entry, but maybe he dies later?)

Comment: (In case you're curious, a Sol on Mars is about 24½ hours.)

Comment: Actually, the only reason I know that is because of your post really. But if the book is fine enough, I'm sure I'll enjoy it. A Sol is a day? I thought it was a *place*.

Comment: Oh, the "surviving" bit in the quote took place before the beginning of the book. He means that he survived the things that happened on Sol 6. ("Sol 6" meaning "the sixth Martian day of the mission.")

Comment: Oh, then that was not a spoiler! Great to know!